# Is Leibnizian calculus embeddable in first order logic?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, math-history, first-order-logic, philosophy

We just published an article making what we feel is a plausible case in favor of an affirmative answer in *Foundations of Science*, see preprint [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03501). The basic argument is that while such a requirement may seem very limitative, such an embedding seems possible with a small number of additional ingredients like a black box for returing the sum of a series, and I was curious how well-supported this appears and if there are aspects that may have been overlooked.

Crosslisted at [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3798) without generating much response.

Note. *Leibnizian calculus* is calculus as it was practiced by Leibniz, in the same sense as *Euclidean geometry* could be interpreted as geometry as practiced by Euclid (though the term often has a different meaning). An example that we give in the paper of the type of mathematics that would not be Leibnizian calculus is a proof of the extreme value theorem, a 19th century argument.